# Rotation of a curve ${g=0}$ while around a point $y_0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, geometry, analysis, differential-geometry

Let us define a smooth manifold by $g: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ that is of class $C^1$, and it is given by
$$
\{y \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid g(y)=0\}.
$$
When fixing a point $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$, I want to slighly "rotate" the manifold as shown in [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5hWd.jpg).

How can I define $g_{\epsilon}$?

I tought of $g_{\epsilon}(y)=g(M_{\epsilon}​(y−y_0​)+y_0​)$, where $(M_{\epsilon}​$ stands for the rotation matrix, but I do not know if such thing exists in n dimensions, or is there a simpler way to define $g_{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Rotations are linear operations in any number of dimensions, and thus are represented by matrices in all of them. So your formula is exactly right.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks for your reply. How can I change the rotation to the right or left? is it by taking $ \pm M_{\epsilon}$ ?

Comment: "Left" and "right" are only meaningful in 2D. In higher dimensions, we have to specify a restriction to 2D before they make sense (in 3D we do that subconsciously with respect to "up" and "down"). For any injective linear transformation $M$, it is the inverse transformation $M^{-1}$ that transforms in the "opposite" direction. For rotations, the inverse in just the transpose of the matrix.